# how to make a text of web address type or email type to a automatic hyperlink tag

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

How to customize the configuration of ckeditor in such a way , if anybody enter a text pattern of email or any web address and ,pressing the Ctrl+Key 'Space' after that text , it'll automatically make that text hyperlink [ Feature similar to the MS-word ] . If anyone have any idea how to implement it .

Answer (score 0):

you would need to implament that on save or on output in java

else you can load a JavaScript on the editor page by passing it into the html and let it modify the entered email if it is on after key Ctrl+Key 'Space' press

so it replaces bla@bla.com with bla@bla.com

[replacewith jquery example](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Comment: if you can't code your self make a request here http://cksource.com/enterprise they will do it for around 20 dollar i think maybe for free